# Discord py - 'id': target.id AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' - in version 1.5.1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys, I got a big problem...**

In my office I use discord.py-1.4.1 and this code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio, os, random
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import NotFound
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
client.remove_command("help")
guild = discord.Guild

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Skipzz-Test-Bot is now online")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    user = payload.user_id
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    category = guild.get_channel(766608102081822730)
    
    if user == 762903825866424320:
        return
    
    if emoji == "":
        member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
        support_role = guild.get_role(765108248583733248)
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
            support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        }
        ticket_nr = random.randint(100,999)
        await category.create_text_channel(f'ticket-{ticket_nr}', overwrites=overwrites)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def reaction(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("This is a test for a reaction!")
    await msg.add_reaction("")

client.run(MY_TOKEN)
```

Everything works fine - if the user clicks on the emoji - a channel gets created - only the user and the support-role have access to this channel.

But at home I am using the newest version of discord.py-1.5.1

and I get an error on the same code

> ```
> 'id': target.id AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
> ```

WHY?????

Did they change anything important? If yes how do I have to edit my code?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think this problem refers to the API changes in "1.5.0". In particular: "Members and presences will no longer be retrieved due to an API change.". More Details: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#api-changes

Comment: So that means - I can nothing do about it? Only if I install discord.py 1.4.1 again it works? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions, you need to define it to getting channels, members etc. You have to define it before you define the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='!')`.

```py
import discord
import asyncio, os, random
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import NotFound
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

For more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).

Comment: Ah okay - and that would be all I need? :D